# Quand on tient à quelqu’un, on le retient

Tags: sens

[France 2 tweeted](https://twitter.com/France2tv/status/679224909667504128):

> "Quand on tient à quelqu’un, on le retient." Découvrez la campagne #SécuritéRoutière #RetenirUnAmi avec @michelcymes

What is the meaning of the first sentence?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez S'agissant d'un twit, on peut difficilement donner plus de contexte. Vu que la phrase n'est pas triviale à comprendre avec un dictionnaire, et est suffisamment courte pour qu'on ne puisse pas la découper plus, je pense que la question est valable pour ce site.

Comment: @Gilles: On indique dans la question les définitions trouvées dans le dictionnaire, ça évite les réponses qui ne font que donner des définitions… De plus le contexte existe (en dehors du tweet), il se trouve très facilement en faisant une recherche et devrait aussi apparaitre dans la question. Tout porte à croire que l'auteur n'en a pas fait une seule. Pour moi « J'ai lu une phrase, qu'est-ce qu'elle veut dire ? » n'est pas un format de question acceptable. Soit. Le sens de la phrase n'est pas évident. Pour autant, ça n'empêche pas quelques efforts élémentaires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This tweet is related to a [road safety association campaign](http://www.securite-routiere.gouv.fr/medias/campagnes/quand-on-tient-a-quelqu-un-on-le-retient2) that started [four years ago](http://www.securite-routiere.gouv.fr/medias/campagnes/quand-on-tient-a-quelqu-un-on-le-retient).

When you value someone, you hold on/keep him/her at your home to prevent the risks associated with driving under alcohol influence.

Answer (score 3):

*Tenir à qqun* - to value, be attached to someone.

*Retenir* - to keep, remember

There are other possibilities, but without context it could mean "When you value someone, you remember him/it."

Comment: Désolé en fait j'ai downvoté un peu compulsivement en connaissant déjà le contexte, et je n'aurais pas dû (je rectifie dès que je peux). La question est simplement mal posée, et tu as raison, c'est la réponse la plus évidente sans contexte. J'ai bien voté pour la fermer, mais visiblement on pense que je n'aurais pas dû.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. “Retenir” is awkward when applied to a person. “You remember him” is not at all a natural interpretation of this sentence.

Comment: _Retenir_ feels more like "hold on to" (people you care about) in this context imho, but not native speaker here.

Answer (score 2):

appart from the definitions explained and the meaning, this is a kind of joke usual in french:

- a rhyme : tient / retient
- a closeness between two verbs: tenir / retenir, with two meanings for tenir

to get a good slogan.

Comment: +1 yeah I heard that once

Comment: @Educ another one: à bon chat, bon rat !

Comment: I didn't get it could u elaborate it

Comment: @Educ : good cat => good rat . in reverso: diamond cut diamond, it is tit for tat